# How to send a website to a second activity in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to create an application that allows sending any website as data, but when I write the address it does not load in the second activity.

```
Note: in the manifest I already put this code <uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is my code

```
MainActivity

 bt_ir.setOnClickListener {

            val sitio = pt_sitio.text.toString()
            val inten = Intent (this, MainActivity2_Webview::class.java)
            inten.putExtra("Clave", sitio)
            startActivity(inten)
        }

Second Activity

        val intent = intent
        val name = intent.getStringExtra("Clave")
        wv_sitio.loadUrl("http//:${name}")

        bt_atras.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your URL string after `http`, it should be `://` instead of `//:`

As well as that, if you're using `http` instead of `https`, you might need to set `usesCleartextTraffic` in the manifest to `true` - this was the default before API 28, [if you target 28+ it defaults to false and you have to explicitly enable it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic).

There's also a more complex system with a [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) if you want more fine control over which sites are allowed through.

Depending on what's going on in your WebView, you might need use [setMixedContentMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMixedContentMode(int)) to `ALWAYS_ALLOW` or something - this is a security problem, so using https would be better, but that's up to you!